# Typescript Axios types in return

Tags: typescript, axios

I have an axios post that does this

```
public myFunc(auth: string) {
    return axios.post(`${auth_provider_base_url}/access`, {
        code: auth
    }).then((resp) => resp.data);
}
```

Which returns a hash (I suppose)

but can I return it as an interface?

```
interface Iface {
    field: string;
}

public myFunc(auth: string): IFace {
    return axios.post(`${auth_provider_base_url}/access`, {
        code: auth
    }).then((resp) => resp.data);
}
```

Or do I even want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could simply set the type in the `post` function like this `axios.post<Iface>(...)` and it will return this type `AxiosResponse<Iface>`
Here is how could be using your code:

```
interface Iface {
    field: string;
}

public async myFunc(auth: string): Promise<Iface> {
    const axiosResponse = await axios.post<Iface>(`${auth_provider_base_url}/access`, {
        code: auth
    });
    return axiosResponse.data;
}
```

However, in this way you are only interested in the data from the request, you are ignoring some other properties that you will find in the `axiosResponse`

As a side note, I modified your function to use async/await, it could help you on better error handling, but that is up to you.